# Why am I getting very different results from jags and stan

Tags: r, jags, stan

Why am I getting different results from jags and stan in a simple linear regression model?

Using `Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length` in the `iris` dataset as an example.

OLS:

```
> lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length, iris)

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Petal.Length  
      4.3066        0.4089
```

stan:

```
data{
    vector[150] Sepal_Length;
    vector[150] Petal_Length;
}
parameters{
    real b0;
    real b1;
    real<lower=0,upper=20> sigma;
}
model{
    vector[150] mu;
    sigma ~ uniform( 0 , 20 );
    b1 ~ normal( 0 , 10 );
    b0 ~ normal( 0 , 10 );
    for ( i in 1:150 ) {
        mu[i] = b0 + b1 * Petal_Length[i];
    }
    Sepal_Length ~ normal( mu , sigma );
}
```

```
> precis(model.stan)
      mean   sd 5.5% 94.5% n_eff Rhat4
b0    4.31 0.08 4.18  4.43 12251     1
b1    0.41 0.02 0.38  0.44 12370     1
sigma 0.41 0.02 0.37  0.45 15591     1
```

rjags:

- Declare same model

```
> jags_code <- "model{
+   for(i in 1:N){
+     Sepal_Length[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
+     mu[i] <- b0 + b1*Petal_Length[i]
+   }  
+   b0~dnorm(0, 10)
+   b1~dnorm(0, 10)
+   sigma~dunif(0, 20)
+   tau <- pow(sigma, -2)
+ }
+ "
```

- Run model

```
> jags.model(textConnection(jags_code), 
+            data = list(Sepal_Length = iris$Sepal.Length, Petal_Length = iris$Petal.Length, N = nrow(iris)), 
+            n.chains = 4) -> model.jags
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
Graph information:
   Observed stochastic nodes: 150
   Unobserved stochastic nodes: 3
   Total graph size: 396

Initializing model

  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100%
>
```

- Sample posterior

```
> coda.samples(model.jags, variable.names = c("b0", "b1", "sigma"), n.iter = 10000) -> posterior.jags
  |**************************************************| 100%
> 
> apply(posterior.jags[[1]], 2, mean)
       b0        b1     sigma 
4.0457213 0.4654953 0.4257200
```

Ther result is different from ols and stan. I am using very flat priors here.

Comment: In your JAGS code you have, in line 3, `dnorm` parameterized by the mean and the precision (inverse of variance), whereas in lines 5 and 6, it appears to be parameterized by the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @jbowman The normal likelihood in jags is specified with mean and precision. I declared a uniform prior for the standard deviation then calculated the precision by pow(sd, -2). Is that not consistent with my stan model?

Comment: In the JAGS code you have `b0` and `b1` priors with mean 0 and precision 10, i.e., std. deviation about 0.31.   (The point was, unclear though it may have been, that you have an inconsistent parameterization in the JAGS code...)

Comment: When you change the priors to `dnorm(0, 0.1)` you get `4.3006245 0.4102885 0.4100701 ` for the three posterior means, consistent with STAN and `lm`.

Comment: Ahhh I see it now. So silly.. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, I've done that a hundred times (at least!)